# Why doesn't a using-declaration work to solve the diamond problem?

Tags: c++, inheritance, subclass, using-directives, diamond-problem

Please consider the following code:

```
struct A
{
    void f()
    {
    }
};

struct B1 : A
{
};

struct B2 : A
{
};

struct C : B1, B2
{
    void f() // works
    {
        B1::f();
    }
    //using B1::f; // does not work
    //using B1::A::f; // does not work as well
};

int main()
{
    C c;
    c.f();

    return 0;
}
```

I kindly ask you not to copy paste a standard reply on how to solve the diamond problem ("use virtual inheritance"). What I am asking here is why doesn't a using-declaration work in this case. The exact compiler error is:

```
In function 'int main()':
prog.cpp:31:6: error: 'A' is an ambiguous base of 'C'
  c.f();
```

I got the impression a using-declaration should work from this example:

```
struct A
{
    void f()
    {
    }
};

struct B
{
    void f()
    {
    }
};

struct C : A, B
{
    using A::f;
};

int main()
{
    C c;
    c.f(); // will call A::f

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need a::f as virtual method to override it

Comment: I am not overriding anything. I am hiding.

Comment: [Works here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3e301b60717fd4dc). What compiler are you using?

Comment: Probably: There is no B1::f (the name is resolved as A::f), hence you have two A::f (one in B1 and one in B2)

Comment: @0x499602D2: Remove the `C::f` definition.

Comment: It probably has to do with how name lookup is performed. It seems that the `using` directive is added to the overload set *after* the unqualified name lookup. In particular, if you uncomment the `using` directive but remove the explicit call `c.f()`, your program compiles.

Comment: Re the title, you were the unfortunate victim of a rule that is a net benefit in a _huge_  majority of cases.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit : I +1'd your comment because you have shown empathy towards my suffering, anyway I beg to differ: such a rule is frankly in[s]ane because it is useless when it's not harmful. The bad guys can simply write "issue" in the title box, or "proble.m", and then write "plz help how declare pointer cheerz" in the body. There's no automagic word filter saving you, you'll have to hunt low-quality questions down one by one. And let *me* write "diamond problem", for God's sake. :)

Comment: Meta discussion: [The Halting Issue](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/115250/7586), and [The title word filter is one of the worst ideas ever implemented on SO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/112944/7586)

Comment: @Kobi: bottom line, it's in[s]ane. :)

Comment: More relevant is http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108815/let-users-with-sufficient-reputation-use-problem-in-titles#comment300489_111000

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Someone else can find the standard quote but I'm going to explain conceptually.

It doesn't work because a *using-declaration* **only affects name lookup.**

Your *using-declaration* causes name lookup to succeed where it would otherwise fail, that is, it tells the compiler *where to find the function `f`.* But it does not tell it *which `A` subobject `f` acts on*, that is, which one will be passed as the implicit `this` parameter when `f` is called.

There is only a single function `A::f` even though there are two `A` subobjects of `C`, and it takes an implicit `this` argument of type `A*`. In order to call it on a `C` object, `C*` must be implicitly converted to `A*`. This is always ambiguous, and is not affected by any *using-declarations*.

(This makes more sense if you put data members inside `A`. Then `C` would have two of each such data member. When `f` is called, if it accesses data members, does it access the ones in the `A` subobject inherited from `B1`, or the ones in the `A` subobject inherited from `B2`?)

Comment: So, the using-declare is not smart enough, otherwise should access the ones in A inherited from B1.

Answer (score 29):

There's a note in [namespace.udecl]/p17 that addresses this situation directly:

> [ *Note*: Because a *using-declaration* designates a base class member
>   (and not a member subobject or a member function of a base class
>   subobject), a *using-declaration* cannot be used to resolve inherited
>   member ambiguities. For example,
>
> ```
> struct A { int x(); };
> struct B : A { };
> struct C : A {
>     using A::x;
>     int x(int);
> };
> struct D : B, C {
>     using C::x;
>     int x(double);
> };
> int f(D* d) {    
>     return d->x(); // ambiguous: B::x or C::x
> }
> ```
>
> —*end note* ]

Comment: Great, thanks. I am willing to accept this answer, but can you explain me in your words what they mean with "designates a base class member (and not a member subobject or a member function of a base class subobject)". Ehm... what?

Comment: @T.C. The normative reference seems to be [expr.ref]/5.

Comment: @gd1 The using-declaration designates a member (`A::x()`) and not a subobject (either the `C` or the `B` that contain the `A` that has the `x()`). You need to specify the subobject to resolve the ambiguity.

Comment: @Brian Sure, that's what ultimately renders the call ill-formed, but to be complete you'd need to go through a lot more than that. Since the question didn't ask for a full language-lawyer analysis, I figured that the note is good enough.

Comment: @gd1 I was going to, but then Brian posted his answer, and I don't have much to add to it.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to T.C.'s answer, I'd like to add that the name lookup in derived class is explained in the standard pretty much in detail in section 10.2.

Here what is said about processing of using-declarations :

> **10.2/3:** The lookup set (...) consists of two component sets: the declaration set, a set of members named f; and the subobject set, a set of subobjects where declarations of these members (possibly including
>   using-declarations) were found. In the declaration set, **using-declarations are replaced** by the members they designate, and type declarations (including
>   injected-class-names) are replaced by the types they designate.

So when you try to declare in `struct C`

```
using B1::f; // you hope to make clear that B1::f is to be used
```

according to the lookup rules, your compiler nevertheless finds the possible candidates:  `B1::f` and `B2::f` so that it's still ambiguous.

Comment: How does this relate to Brian's answer?

Comment: Brian's very clear answer was posted in the same time.  I wouldn't have posted my answer if I'd read his one first ;-)  But I don't delete mine, just to leave the standard reference for the language lawyers who might be interested.

Comment: I don't think your answer is useless, I am just trying to understand how it relates to Brian's. I don't see how 10.2/3 would explain what I see, whereas the note reported by T.C. and Brian's explanation of it make sense to me--when used together ;)

Comment: I've completed the quote with the first sentence.  My explanation is solely focused on the declarations set (and the fact that tehre is ambiguity left).  Brian addresses as well the subobject set, and the special case of your example.